# How to write/create a CSV with fixed width columns?

Tags: python, csv

I have columnar data in which a column of data ranges widely in width.
I would like to display this data in a monospace font, for easy viewing while additionally retaining the capabilities of parsing that data with common csv handlers.

<sub>I am willing to accept that a strip/trim operations may need to be done by the parsing lib and I am not worried about leading/trailing white space being preserved.</sub>

How can I write a csv with fixed width data columns? Is this possible with the `csv` module?

In Open/Libre Office terms, this is called "Fixed column width" in the Export Text File options.

#### Example

```
data = [
    ('Brown Fox Jumps Over', 'Lorem ipsum',),
    ('The Lazy', 'dolor sit amet,',),
    ('Dog', 'consectetur adipiscing elit.',),
]
```

Desired output

```
"Header 1            ", "Header 2                    ",
"Brown Fox Jumps Over", "Lorem ipsum                 ",
"The Lazy            ", "dolor sit amet,             ",
"Dog                 ", "consectetur adipiscing elit.",
```

Chiefly I'm looking for a tool to scan a dataset for its widest values and format then entire column to that width for all columns because [writing one myself](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reinventing_the_wheel) inline feels inappropriate.

Comment: If the columns have a fixed width, you wouldn't need a comma to separate them.

Comment: Do you mean that the text file would have fixed-width columns, or do you mean that the presentation in Excel or LibreOffice would be fixed-width?

Comment: As @chepner suggests, if it truly is a CSV file, then the `csv` module should handle it.  If you tried it and it didn't work, post the details.

Comment: @ScottHunter - I think the OP is using `csv` as a generic term.  What it sounds like he actually wants is a fixed-width file.  OTOH, I'm not certain enough based on his question to go in and edit it for clarity.  He may actually want a CSV file with fixed-width columns. :-D

Answer (score 3):

Use `str.format`?

```
In [1]: '{0: <10}'.format('lorem')
Out[1]: 'lorem     '

In [2]: '{0: <10}'.format('lorem ipsum')
Out[2]: 'lorem ipsum'
```

Something like,

```
lines = ['lorem ipsum', 'dolor sit amet']

with open('foo.txt', 'w') as foo:
   for line in lines:
       words = line.split()
       formatted = ' '.join(['{0: <5}'.format(word) for word in words])
       foo.write(formatted + '\n')
```

---

```
$ cat foo.txt
lorem ipsum
dolor sit   amet
```

---

You could then use [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#files-with-fixed-width-columns) to read it quite elegantly

```
In [1]: df = pd.read_fwf('foo.txt', colspecs=[(0,5),(6,11),(12,17)], header=None)

In [2]: df
Out[2]:
       0      1     2
0  lorem  ipsum   NaN
1  dolor    sit  amet
```